# APK-Multi-Tool "Access is deniend error" while decompiling apk

Tags: java, android, apk

I, i'm using APK-Multi-Tool to mod an apk but when i try do decompile it says me that there's an error. That is the log:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
Access is denied.
```

does anyone know hot to bypass this error?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is possibly about violating software licensing terms and not about creating software.

Comment: thank you for the useless reply. Pretty much everything could be used to do illegal stuff, in my case i'm just trying to decompile an apk, that isn't so illegal. If you don't know how to answer my question don't start accusing...